# Windows Server 2008 - automatic user logon on power on

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

I use Windows Server 2008.

I am looking for a way to automatically start a user session when I power on my workstation.

Scenario:
1) I deploy a remote virtual machine with Windows Server 2008;
2) I configure Logon script on this VM to run some processes;
3) I need to start a user session automatically when I power on this VM to run the the automatic tests there.
Note, I can't run the tests under the System. I need a user session with Desktop because I use TestComplete tests to make GUI testing.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this ?
I have already tried automatic Windows Logon functionality but seems it doesn't help anyway. When I restart my VM - it doesn't start user's session automatically.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[Setting DefaultUsername and DefaultPassword values in conjunction with AutoAdminLogon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231) *does* work with Windows Server 2008. Where exactly did you have problems with this process?

Answer (score 2):

Try to import the following registry data (first save as "AutoLogon.reg", then right-click -> merge):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"DefaultDomainName"="YOUR_DOMAIN"
"DefaultUserName"="YOUR_USER"
"DefaultPassword"="YOUR_PASSWORD"
"ForceAutoLogon"="1"
"AutoAdminLogon"="1"
"LegalNoticeCaption"=""
"LegalNoticeText"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AutoLogonChecked]
@="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system]
"LegalNoticeCaption"=""
"LegalNoticeText"=""
```

Now restart your machine, and check if that user logged in (task manager -> users) from another user session.

**EDIT :**
If you're getting **black screenshots** or other GUI problems (when using Selenium, Test Complete, etc.), then create a batch file that disconnects Remote Desktop, instead of closing the RDP session with the regular X button:

```
%windir%\system32\tscon.exe %SESSIONNAME% /dest:console
```

Answer (score 0):

For the graphical user fans under us, see this tutorial:

http://www.itsupportguides.com/windows-7/windows-7-auto-logon-with-domain-computer/